# How do you include LuaPlus into your project?

Tags: c++, scripting, include, lua

I downloaded the visual2008 file from here(http://luaplus.org/projects/luaplus/files), but I don't know how to add it to my project. It's not like the other libraries where I just had to add the include directory to my Visual Studio folder and the bin to my system32 or project folder. There are no header files either. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 professional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I remember downloading LuaPlus for the first time and thinking the same thing--"Where are the headers?"  What you'll want to do is just clone the repository located on [GitHub](https://github.com/jjensen/luaplus51-all) and use that to build LuaPlus yourself.  The author helpfully included batch files to create different project files (incl. VS2010).  You can then use the project files to build LuaPlus and you'll naturally also have the headers & source files as well.  I don't recall if it included Lua's source already or if you have to do it yourself manually (this only takes a minute to do, however).

Comment: Ah, okay, it worked! After building the release version of the project(Which had some errors mostly Qt related that I didn't worry about) I went to luaplus51-all\build2010\win32-release\LUAPLUS\Src\LuaPlus\StaticLib and put all the files(not the folders) into VS's lib directory and copied luaplus51-all\build2010\win32-release\LUAPLUS to my C:\ directory and added it to "Additional include directories" in VS, added luaplusstatic51_1201.release.lib to linker, and included the LuaPlus.h header and it worked xD Took me like 10 seconds to realize I needed to use the LuaPlus namespace though.

Comment: @NaturalDre Glad to help out :)  Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it did the trick.