# Why are there no header files to include when building LuaPlus?

Tags: build, codeblocks, include-path, luaplus

From this question's answer, it seems as though this should be simple: [How do you include LuaPlus into your project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129825/how-do-you-include-luaplus-into-your-project)

This is absolutely ridiculous though. It is so dumb that you have to build this (along with such an awful website), but there are absolutely no tutorials on this either. Horrible documentation on getting it installed.

I read something about building it using the "jam" stuff, but that is alien lingo to me and sounds asinine. Why not just make this simple? Most libraries just let you download them straight up, extract, link, and wallah! I've built libraries before, and it was extremely simple and easy.

Anyway, I successfully built the library in Code::Blocks, but that isn't the problem. The problem is it only builds the library. Where are the header files to add to the include directory?

I tried messing around, but I had errors just dumping what I thought the header files were into a directory and including it.

I read online, people who use Visual Studio to build don't have a problem, and it creates all the header files. The only thing that results from my Code::Blocks build is the library file.

This is a PITA just to get to use, and I've already been at it 2 hours and the only way I can work with it is if I include the entire source in my project (which is just ridiculous).

Answer (score 0):

edit2: Ergh! LuaPlus edits Lua itself, so you have to remove your link to Lua. LuaPlus has Lua in it. So F***ing ridiculous. Just let people download the library and just link simply for god's sake. A huge middle finger to needlessly complicated crap.

edit: Nevermind, this isn't the correct answer. Now I'm getting all kinds of stupid errors.

I guess the first time I copied over all the header files, I did something wrong because now it works just as it should.

For anyone interested, you just copy/paste all of the header files (shown here [image]

Minus LuaPlusAll.cpp, src/lua.c, and src/luac.c

Then paste them in your search directory

lib/libLuaPlus.a
include/[paste here]

Link the library & include directory, tell Code::Blocks to use "libLuaPlus" and wallah!

No idea why I had problems with this. Must have been following someone's bad directions (causing me to mess up somewhere).